# Why is instance variable undefined?

Tags: javascript

I dont understand one thing:

```
 var comein = document.getElementById("comein");

 var enter = new Expand({ elem : comein });

function Expand (options) {
    this._elem = options.elem;
    console.log(this._elem); // i have a div element    
}

Expand.prototype = {        
    check : function () {

        var comInClassName = this._elem.className; // i have an error: this._elem is undefined

        if (comInClassName == "open"){
          this.close();
        }
        if (comInClassName == "close"){
          this.open();
        }
    }
}
log_in.addEventListener("click",  enter.check, false);
```

Why I have an error in prototype method if in Expand i have a normal element? Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you *calling* the "check" function?

Comment: log_in.addEventListener("click",  enter.check, false);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you *call* `check`. If you call it like this:

```
enter.check();
```

....then within the call, `this` will refer to the `enter` object and it will have an `_elem` property. If, on the other hand, you set it up to be called like this:

```
enter._elem.addEventListener('click', enter.check, false);
```

...then within the call (when the event occurs), `this` will *not* refer to `enter`, but rather to `this._elem`, and so it has no `_elem` property.

This happens because in JavaScript (for now), `this` within a function call is defined entirely by how the function is called, not where the function is defined. If you call it as part of an expression retrieving the function reference from an object:

```
enter.check();
```

...then `this` refers to the object you got the function reference from. But if you call it separately, as with the `addEventListener` call above, it doesn't.

If you're on an ECMAScript5-enabled environment (or if you have a decent ES5 shim in place), you can fix that by using [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
enter._elem.addEventListener('click', enter.check.bind(enter), false);
```

`bind` returns a function that, when called, will turn around and call the underlying function using the given `this` value (`enter`, in our case).

More to explore (on my blog):

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: yes, you right, if i call enter.check() - there is no problem, but how then i can add Event Listener for this check ?

Comment: @user1506183: Just as you were entering that comment, I was adding a note about `Function#bind`. The linked articles also go into how to deal with this in some detail.